# can i use foreach inside an another foreach?

Tags: php

can i use foreach inside an another foreach? is it fair?

Comment: Have you tried it? And what does "fair" mean?

Comment: if you need to then you have to...do you have a choice?? go on i think its fair.

Comment: I wouldn't call it fair. Why not give `for` a chance? Or maybe `while`? It's not fair to be prejudiced towards other constructs, you know.

Comment: @Sebastian P.: You just won the thread.

Comment: Only thing you need to remember, is that nesting loops (you can do that with `for` and `while` as well) is dramatically increasing number of operations your script does (and thus it's execution time)

Comment: FWIW, I'm wondering if the original question was related to doing a foreach over one array, while trying to do an internal foreach over the *same* array. This is not really doable, though, as the internal loop will affect the array pointer, essentially screwing up the external loop over that same array. I think.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by 'is it fair', but you most certainly can nest foreach loops. The following code gives an example of how to do so;

```
$locations = array(
  'my_house' => array('hallway', 'living_room', 'dining_room', 'kitchen', 'bedroom', 'toilet'),
  'my_office' => array('entrance', 'work_room', 'toilet')
);

foreach( $locations as $building => $rooms ) {
  echo "Listing rooms in $building... <br />";

  foreach( $rooms as $room ) {
    echo $room . "<br />";
  }

  echo "<br /><br />";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes that is 100% ok & valid if you need it.

PS. Try before ask ;-)

Comment: This can easily be answered as a comment

Comment: Congrats on reaching 3000 rep; now go forth and close questions! (May or may not be this one.)

Comment: @Shakti I am sure that any answer is not a comment :-)